# CSS Grid: how to force one child size between 1fr and 2fr?

Tags: css, css-grid

Requirement: force the second child in Grid container to adapt between sizes of 1fr and 2fr, automatically based on content.

AFAIK, `minmax()` won't work for the case, since the first value can't be an `fr` unit.

[image]

Below is a real example, (but I hard-coded them to be 1:1 and 1:2) at the moment.

However, I want it to automatically fit between 1:1 and 1:2 based on the overall contents inside.

[image]

Comment: Not a case for Css-grid, this is a flexbox issue.

Comment: or use a six column grid and span either 3 col or 2 and 4 ...

Comment: What would be the required situation for it to be 1fr and what for 2fr?

Comment: My reading is that the second div can be any size BETWEEN 1fr and 2fr,but perhaps I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: Sorry that I'm not being clear. So I want the second child's size to adapt based on content in the grid container, however maximum is 2fr but minimum is 1fr. I've updated my illustration

Comment: Could you describe exactly what content you are talking about here. Is it the content in the first element? I’m not understanding what the 1fr means in the diagrams.

Comment: I think we need a runnable snippet that gives examples of the possible distribution of content across various rows. I am not clear under what circumstances the grid would have a 1:2width split as opposed to a 1:1. What would force say 1:1.5?

Comment: Updated a real example above

Answer (score 0):

With flexbox you can just set `min-width: 33%;` on the child items. I don’t know of a way to do the same in a grid, though, because setting a grid child’s min-width to 33% means one third of the **column** width, not one third of the **grid** width.

```css
.d1 {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  border: 2px solid lime;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.d1>div {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  min-width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div>A short value</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin feugiat turpis vitae eros ultricies pretium. Maecenas suscipit sit amet nunc ut hendrerit. Donec ac sapien bibendum ipsum pretium fringilla sed placerat velit. Maecenas sodales accumsan nisi, eu molestie ex. Vivamus ac nunc velit. Donec eget elit nec eros venenatis tempor. Nullam libero diam, lacinia vel dictum ac, euismod a sem. Donec interdum venenatis mattis. Suspendisse fermentum arcu lacinia metus lacinia, vitae suscipit justo commodo. Nunc suscipit, nisi eget rutrum porta, orci ligula porttitor nunc, id elementum mi dolor sed ligula.</div>
</div>

<div class="d1">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin feugiat turpis vitae eros ultricies pretium. Maecenas suscipit sit amet nunc ut hendrerit. Donec ac sapien bibendum ipsum pretium fringilla sed placerat velit. Maecenas sodales accumsan nisi, eu molestie ex. Vivamus ac nunc velit. Donec eget elit nec eros venenatis tempor. Nullam libero diam, lacinia vel dictum ac, euismod a sem. Donec interdum venenatis mattis. Suspendisse fermentum arcu lacinia metus lacinia, vitae suscipit justo commodo. Nunc suscipit, nisi eget rutrum porta, orci ligula porttitor nunc, id elementum mi dolor sed ligula.</div>
  <div>A short value</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, this won't fit my need, as I have 2 rows. Please have a look at my real-world use case above